# MYSQL GROUP BY and ORDER BY with ABS

Tags: mysql

I need to select the "bundle" entries from the table below but only if a bundle exists other wise select track 1 from each release. Each release has a unique "cat_no" which is why I need to use GROUP BY.

```
SELECT * FROM cds  
WHERE genre='rock'  
GROUP BY cat_no  
ORDER BY ABS(track) DESC  
LIMIT 0,3
```

This what I have tried but I am sometimes getting track 1 when there is a bundle for that release.

Table

```
genre cat_no  track  
rock  001     1      
rock  001     2      
rock  001     bundle 
rock  002     1      
rock  002     2      
rock  002     bundle 
rock  003     1     
rock  003     2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to sort records before the grouping -

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT * FROM cds WHERE genre = 'rock' ORDER BY IF(track = 'bundle', 0, 1)) t
GROUP BY
  cat_no;
```

Comment: Thanks that has worked but can you explain what the 't' is for and I'm assuming the track = 'bundle', 0, 1 is an order of precedence?

Comment: 1. 't' is a subquery alias (MySQL needs it); 2. Yes, IF(...) is used to place 'bundle' before the other `truck` numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select genre, cat_no, max(track) from t
where track in ('1', 'bundle')
group by genre, cat_no
```

We're actually taking advantage of the order ('bundle' appears after '1'). I don't understand the ABS on track... what's the intention of it?

Given your example data, the previous query would result in:

```
+-------+--------+--------+
| GENRE | CAT_NO | TRACK  |
+-------+--------+--------+
| rock  |      1 | bundle |
| rock  |      2 | bundle |
| rock  |      3 | 1      |
+-------+--------+--------+
```

Let me know if this helps.